# Using Rotativa in asp.net 5

Tags: pdf, asp.net-core, actionresult, rotativa

I’m trying to use the Rotativa nugget package to get a pdf from an view I have.
My method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult test()
{
   return new ActionAsPdf("Index", new { name = "Test" }) { FileName = "Test.pdf" };
}
```

I get the error message :” The type ‘ActionResult’ is defined in an assembly that is not reference. Add the Assembly reference System.Web.Mvc.” But in asp.net 5 mvc 6 the reference to mvc is Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc. Does anybody know a workaround on this or a nugget package that does the same as Rotativa that works with asp5?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest System.Web.Mvc nuggets package, then it will be okey.

Comment: "ASP.NET 5 is no longer based on System.Web.dll, but is instead based on a set of granular and well factored NuGet packages allowing you to optimize your app to have just what you need..."

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/aspnet.html

Looks like the rotativa's friends haven't updated rotativa for a while now; I used to use it, its great, but for now is not posible make a proper implementation over ASP.Net 5, please somebody correct me if I'm wrong (I hope I am).